# How to read file names and word count in respective files in Hadoop?

Tags: python, hadoop, sequencefile

I am trying to fetch file names from sequence file from hadoop with the help of dumbo package of python.
But it provides me some kind of identifier. How can i map this to file name?

Below is my steps on hadoop system for getting filenames :

***Steps 1)* Generating Sequence file**

Command :

```
hadoop jar /mnt/Clustering/Checking/AllJars/binarypig-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.endgame.binarypig.util.BuildSequenceFileFromDir /mnt/Clustering/Checking/text_files text_files_seq
```

***Step 2)* Running python script on sequence file through hadoop**

Command:

```
dumbo start dumbo_map_red.py -input text_files_seq -output out_res -hadoop /usr/local/hadoop
```

***Step 3)* Getting output in local directory**

Command:

```
dumbo cat out_res/part-* -hadoop /usr/local/hadoop > out_res.txt
```

where dumbo_map_red.py is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def mapper(key, value):
    yield key, 1

def reducer(key, values):
    yield key, sum(values)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import dumbo
    dumbo.run(mapper, reducer)
```

Please help me know how to fetch filenames.
If their is other package in python which will allow me to work that way, please let me know..

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the hint of mapping identifier in sequence file to actual file.

**The identifier is MD5 of file in the directory.**